# Why Closing a File Stream in Java is so Important

Tags: java, file

With huge advancements in CUPs able to process mass amounts of information in fractions of seconds, why is it important that I close a file stream?

Comment: The OS (Linux, for example) has limit for number of opened descriptors. More info: [Why is number of open files limited in Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux)

Comment: The number of open files is limited, as low as 1000 and if you run out of file handles this doesn't trigger a GC, your program will just get IOExceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that not all devices are the same, platforms like mobile(smartphones and tablets) need to be as efficient as possible. Or if the application has a big user base, maybe when 400 people are logged in there wont be that many problems, but what happens when it goes to ~40k? You have to make your code as versatile as possible, always think about scalability.